# 404 - File or directory not found in HTTPS

Tags: iis

I am using IIS 6.1.

I host an ASP site IIS under default site.
When I access that that through Http it's working.
But when access that through HTTPS It's showing

"404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.[image: 404 - File or directory not found.]"

Comment: check your https binding for all sites in IIS,your https  must be pointing to another website.

Comment: thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the answer. In web binding some other IP has been mapped for https.